# Pyinstaller ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Hi i have install piinstaler using pip all is ok. But when i even try to use `pyinstaller --version` i am recieviinf error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2662, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2316, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2322, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ..depend import bindepend
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ..utils.win32.winmanifest import RT_MANIFEST
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 97, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winresource
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed:  The specified module could not be found.
```

- Python 3.5.4 32 bit(shows when using python --version)
- Windows 10 64 -bit
- PyQt 5

All modules for pyinstaler also was installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have python 64 bit, sorry my mistake